Changing Object
yall am trying to find a way to change my mesh the way it looks. I want to change it like the image below. 
the edge dark like shadows and whit are the outer edges.
Can anyone direct me to where I can change it its location in the .......
Thanks

I would strongly recommend for future posts you find titles that roughly describe what the question is about to attract more people which might have a solution for your problem - "changing object" is very broad, does not really show why "changing" is an issue to be solved and it's especially not at all what is going on here in the screenshot.

Try turning on Cavity on the Viewport Shading dropdown.


OMG, thank you. I just need it to make a report, since I have memory lose. i would like to rewrite thing down or come back here. Thanks. everyone else also.

That will only show in the viewport of course not in the final render. You'd need to investigate using material shaders if you want it in the final render. If my answer was what you wanted please check it as accepted. Thanks.
